# How to customize python DataFrame scatter plot color?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I plotted a graph (attached) using the python code below. The problem is that the color assigned is very hard for people to tell the difference between each data point. I would like to customize the color scale. Can anyone help with this? Thanks a lot!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
x=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
y=[5,4,3,2,1,1,2,3,4,5]
z=[0.1,0.2,-0.1,0.3,0.05,0.1,-0.1,-0.5,0.25,-0.05]
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y,'z':z})
df.plot.scatter(x='x',y='y',c='z')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a `colormap` argument to `df.plot()`, e.g.

```
df.plot.scatter(x='x',y='y',c='z', colormap='plasma')
```

[image]

From the docs for [pandas.DataFrame.plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

> **`colormap`** : *str or matplotlib colormap object, default None*
>
> Colormap to select colors from. If string, load colormap with that name from matplotlib.

You can check out the matplotlib colormaps (as I used above) in the [colormaps_reference](https://bids.github.io/colormap/).